# How many Type II restrictions enzymes are currently available (commercially)

Tags: restriction-enzymes

How many Type II restrictions enzymes are currently available (commercially) for purchase as of the date of this posting (September 1, 2014)

Comment: A lot. Why do you need to know? It would be very difficult to inventory every enzyme from every manufacturer out there...

Comment: I'm  an exercise for UGR studentS and was trying to stress the diversity out there with an accurate number. Figured this would be a tough one. NEB has always been the most pioneering company for these but I know they don't own all the patents.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is basically a "shopping-list" question, see [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) and [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about biology *per se*, is extremely difficult to answer, and has no use whatsoever to the users of this website (and it seems very little use to the OP as well)

Comment: I disagree @Raoul ! Respectfully. If one is planning a cloning experiment a comprehensive list is the very thing he/she needs. This ? Explores just that. This is one of the most diverse enzymes in nature as well, knowledge about which ones have had their synthesis mastered and an appreciation if that is  perfectly relevant I believe. You can find the reason for this question above, for education.  I don't think it's an answer is impossible either. I will remove the date from the question but I figured it would allow future readers to easily gauge the accuracy of any answers.

Comment: @rhill45 I did not mean any disrespect. It may be that I have a skewed point of view, not being a fundamentalist. I however suggest not to remove the date, since its presence makes your question more compliant with site policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look in [REBASE](http://rebase.neb.com/) finds 15999 type II restriction enzymes of which 616 are listed as having suppliers. Obviously some of these will share recognition and cut sites.

Answer (score 4):

The [Restriction Enzymes](http://www.biocompare.com/Cloning-and-Expression/6525-Restriction-Enzymes/) section at [Biocompare](http://www.biocompare.com) is likely not comprehensive, but short of contacting every single molecular biology company and merging all their inventories into a master list, it's probably the best you can do on short notice. They currently list **289 uniquely-named enzymes**, but I'm not enough of an expert to say how many are similar in activity/recognition sequence, or whether they might also be known by other names not currently listed. For your purposes, however, it'd probably be enough to tell your students that there are on the order of 300 common commercially-available enzymes. Hope this helps.

Comment: downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the [extreme complexity](http://www.particlesciences.com/news/technical-briefs/2009/protein-structure.html) and **quite easy synthesis and customization** of proteins this question is unanswerable. That is to say there is such a great number of potential enzymes from any set domain or with the functionality there of that no one is able to fathom the depth even when restricted to current availability.

Comment: honestly i'm not surprised people dont think that custom enzymes are readily available but its sad someone would -1 because of it